# Alpha color component in Windows GDI

Tags: c, windows, gdi, alpha, blit

I am writing a simple multiplatform GUI in C for my own use. Under Windows I use the GDI API for drawing. My question concerns the possible use of the alpha component of colors for a masked blit function I want to implement. FYI I am familiar with the MaskBlit function of GDI but its description is quite incomprehensible for mere mortals, and it uses a separate monochrome bitmap as mask.

The MS docs state that for GDI the COLORREF data type is 0x00bbggrr and the uppermost byte MUST always be zero. How strict is this rule? Will GDI use (blit) a bitmap in which the alpha channel values are not zero or will it be rejected?

Comment: GDI dates from the stone age, it is a thoroughly 24bpp api at its core.  GDI+ added support for alpha, gdiplus.h header.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, GDI+ seems to be the solution. I have a single file with all the OS dependent drawing functions isolated, they can easily be converted to use GDI+. Although I really dislike c++... :(

Comment: It is actually a C api at its core.  Microsoft could not imagine that anybody would prefer it.  Me neither.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-flatapi-flat

Comment: ...as well as GTK+ is a C API (although it's object-oriented). Not everything which is suffixed with + provides a C++ API by default. (For GTK+, the C++ counterpart is named gtkmm.)

Comment: You mean `MaskBlt`? Also try `AlphaBlend` or `TransparentBlt` if you just need alpha. But GDI+ has lots more goodies.